# Allow window.close(); in Chrome in settings

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I want to use window.close(); for a personal automation script. However, I can't use it because the tab is not opened by `window.open();`, instead by the OS.

In Firefox it is possible to set the flag `allow_scripts_to_close_windows`  to `true` in about:config. However I did not find this option in Chrome. The question is how can you enable the use of window.close(); in Chrome by the settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome

Comment: I was looking into this article. It seems the Chrome configs are not accessible from  about:config anymore.